# $cookie_domain value causes access denied upon login

Tags: drupal, cookies, fckeditor

I have FCK editor installed, and trying to enable FCK file manager.

It tells me that in order to use it, $cookie_domain must be set.

Easy enough, I set it to www.mysite.com. I can log in, register, etc just fine. However I started seeing a number of people get Access Denied after logging in or trying to access any protected area.

Commenting out $cookie_domain, users can get in fine.

I am looking for one of the following:

A. A harmonious answer where FCK file manager and $cookie_domain can be set

-or-

B. An alternative to FCK editor (like CK) that allows in-place file uploading without requiring cookie domain to be set (and interrupting user experience).

Comment: Are _any_ parts of the site (but especially the login form) used/embedded/accessible in/from domains other than your 'normal' one?

Comment: BTW, I can recommend switching to CKEditor - it is [the explicit successor of FCKE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fckeditor#Name_change), so basically just a more recent version of the same codebase, and the [matching Drupal wrapper module ](http://drupal.org/project/ckeditor) works well for us for a while now. (Not sure if it will solve your problem, though ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what wound up working for me (Domain Access is installed):

```
$base_domain = explode('.', $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']);
unset($base_domain[0]);
$base_domain = '.' . implode($base_domain, '.');

$cookie_domain = $base_domain;
```

Answer (score 4):

Change `$cookie_domain` in your `settings.php` into this:

```
$cookie_domain = substr($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], '.'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try setting `$cookie_domain` to simply `mysite.com` instead of `www.mysite.com`. This will avoid problems if users are accessing your site via just `http://mysite.com` or `http://some-subdomain.mysite.com`.

Try as an experiment to use the FCK filemanager when logged in at `http://mysite.com` (no leading www) -- does it fail or work under the current settings?

See under *Domain and Path* on http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html

Comment: I have added the .htaccess part that sends them to www. if not specified. We need to enforce www. Also, I can't just fool with the setting as it is a big ecommerce site and don't want to block anyone from logging in.

Comment: This setting is going to relax the restrictions so I don't think its going to have any blocking effect. Also are you sure that the FCK file manager is the root cause of access denied errors?

Comment: Also, we were getting the same result with just mydomain.com set on a test site before launching. Domain Access is also being utilized. FCK File Manager requires cookie_domain to be set, and in setting it, caused the Access Denied for people. Until you set the cookie_domain, the file manager cannot be used.

Comment: @Kevin: Did you try with leading dot `.mysite.com`? (This would be the [suggested standard](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2109.txt))

Comment: Not yet, I am afraid of locking people out of the site. I will have to try on the dev site and get some people over on it and logging in.

Answer (score 1):

Check the spelling of the domain name. I left an 's' off the domain name in the settings.php file and it caused this problem. Darn, I hate when I do that...

Answer (score 0):

Just clear your browser cache and delete cookies as described [here](http://drupal.org/node/893934)

Good luck!